# How to block accessing wp-content/uploads

Tags: wordpress, image, security

I try to create a Wordpress site for a Photographer, so I block the right click but it always possible too access too the url where images is uploading. I tried to block with the file .htaccess and the plugind "Prevent Direct Access" but it's not working.

There is any thing who can block the access ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.be [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?facebook.com [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?twitter.com [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [F] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent anyone from accessing any PHP files in the `wp-content/uploads` folder, you can create a .htaccess file in the `wp-content/uploads` folder and add the following code to it:

```
# Kill PHP Execution
<Files ~ ".ph(?:p[345]?|t|tml)$">
deny from all
</Files>
```

You can add the below code to your .htaccess file.

```
# Deny access to .htaccess

<Files .htaccess>

Order allow,deny

Deny from all

</Files>
```

Open up your .htaccess found on the root folder of your website then place the block of code bellow:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ dl-file.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

To hide sensitive files in the wp-includes folder, add the following code to the .htaccess file in the root of your site:

```
 # Block wp-includes folder and files
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
 RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
 RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
 RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
 RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks it's help a lot for me !

Comment: @KillianGraas if it's work then please upvote it  so others can use this

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote ...

Comment: Hi there

Does this part

# Deny access to .htaccess

<Files .htaccess>

Order allow,deny

Deny from all

</Files>

Go below the initial code in the wp-content folder or the one at the root?

Thank you!